# seeking htaccess rule to redirect with same URL structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a .htaccess rule which will redirect any link of one domain to another with exact strcuture and if subfolder then a forword slash added to the new redirected URL.

For example -

```
website1.com
to
website2.com

website1.com/support
to 
website2.com/support/

website1.com/user
to 
website2.com/user/
```

I will really appreciate any guide or sample .htaccess code for my situation.

Thank you,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website2.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Hi Sunny, Thank you for your htaccess code but after I use this - website1.com/support/  redirected to website2.com but I need it to go website2.com/support/.

Comment: I had changed the answer a few minutes after answering. Did you try the edited version?